# StackExcange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, node-redis, redis-server

We are experiencing timeouts in our application using Redis. Already investigated but without success. See the timeout error below:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing GET 
USERORGANIZATIONS_D96510A4-A9A2-4DAA-84A9-BB77363DD3EA, inst: 9, mgr: 
ProcessReadQueue, err: never, queue: 24, qu: 0, qs: 24, qc: 0, wr: 1, wq: 1,
in: 65536, ar: 1, clientName: RD00155D008B42, serverEndpoint: 
Unspecified/xxxxxxx.redis.cache.windows.net:xxxx, keyHashSlot: 9735, IOCP: 
(Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: 
(Busy=27,Free=32740,Min=200,Max=32767) (Please take a look at this article 
for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: 
http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
```

If need some more information, just ask me that I'll try to provide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “in: 65536” value in the timeout is very high.  This value indicates how much data is sitting in the client’s socket kernel buffer.  This indicates that the data has arrived at the local machine but has not been read by the application layer yet.  This typically happens when 1) thread pool settings need to be adjusted or 2) when client CPU is running high.  Here are some articles I suggest you read:

[Diagnosing Redis errors on the client side](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/db0e90bedeb3fc4823c2#file-diagnoserediserrors-clientside-md)

[Azure Redis Best Practices](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f#file-redis-bestpractices-general-md)

Comment: The IOCP is fine right? Busy=0 and Min=4, or we need to incrase the minimum IOCP to something like 100?

And Worker should we increase or decrease?

Comment: Perhaps increase the Min counts for both IOCP and Worker to say 200 to start with.

Comment: @CarlDacosta: can you indicate where exactly in the docs did you take the definition of `in`, if you did so from the docs ? My only finding is [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/investigating-timeout-exceptions-in-stackexchange-redis-for-azure-redis-cache/) single article - which specifically the `in`- does not define.